# Logstash not able to retrieve key stored in logstash-keystore

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-jdbc

I am trying to pass a null value to keystore. Logstash is not working and I am getting an error. Same configuration is working if it is not stored in a keystore and hard coded "".
Error :

"Unable to configure plugins: Error while trying to retrieve secret urn:logstash㊙️v1:pos"

Version: 7.4.2
Operating System: Windows 10
This is the config file :
input { file { path => "${path}" start_position => "${pos}" } }
path and pos are already added in keystore.
Does logstash-keystore can't have blank value. Is there any work-around to handle the issue ? Can we give a default value with keystore keys ?

Comment: Why do you need a blank value in the keystore ? for the start position? Just input `0` instead of blank and that should work

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your question/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason you want to input a blank value in the keystore is because you want to start at the beginning (i.e. `start_position => 0`). If that's the case, you have two solutions:

A. Set `0` as the value of `pos` in the keystore instead of blank

B. Simply [remove the `pos` key](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/keystore.html#remove-settings) from the keystore and use a [default value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html#_overview) in the configuration

```
start_position => "${pos:0}"
```

Comment: pos = "" works fine but if same thing is attempted with keystore it fails. Also path,pos is just an example.

Comment: Again, simply remove the value from the keystore and specify a default value in the configuration

Comment: I wanted to use keystore for security purpose as I am not sure if it's gonna be blank or it will contain some value. I can't use plain text.

Comment: And you can still do that... just use a default value as shown in my answer